# Вычесть из строки подстроку

Tags: c++, qt, текст

Есть строка QString DDF1 с n элементами (устройства USB)

Есть строка QString DDF2 с n+1 элементами (добавили флешку)

Нужно получить название этой флешки, но проблема в том, что оно может быть добавлено в середину текста...

Пример:

```
Ввод:
/dev/sda  /dev/sda1  /dev/sdc  /dev/sdc1
/dev/sda  /dev/sda1  /dev/sdb  /dev/sdb1 /dev/sdc  /dev/sdc1
Вывод:
/dev/sdb  /dev/sdb1
```

Comment: Приведите пример строки. Может получится разделить ее на массив строк, где каждый элемент соответствует одному устройству.

Comment: @maestro теперь верно добавил)

Comment: Можете попробовать с помощью метода QString::split разделить строку на массив, используя tab как разделитель. А потом проверять, какие элементы есть во втором массиве, но нет в первом.

Comment: @maestro можете написать - как это делать, т.к. с Qt несильно знаком (учусь)

Comment: Напишу завтра, если никто не опередит

Comment: `QSet<QString> s1` заполните строками из первой строки, `s2` из второй. Потом `s2 -= s1`. То что останется - то, что вам нужно. Вариант из ответа асимптотически быстрее (QSet - хэш таблица, там в среднем O(1) проверка на наличие, но не всегда), но учитывая количество строк в множествах (сколько флешек обычно втыкают? 2? 5? 10?), разницы вы не почувствуете.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Что-то вроде того:

```
QString str1{"/dev/sda  /dev/sda1  /dev/sdc  /dev/sdc1"};
QString str2 { "/dev/sda  /dev/sda1  /dev/sdb  /dev/sdb1 /dev/sdc  /dev/sdc1" }

auto list1 = str1.split(" ");
auto list2 = str2.split(" ");

list1.sort();
list2.sort();
QStringList retval{};
auto secondIter = list1.begin();
for (auto i = list2.begin(); i != list2.end;) {
  if (secondIter == list1.end()) {
    retval.push_back(*i);
    ++i;
  } else {
    if (*i != *secondIter) {
      retval.push_back(*secondIter);
      ++secondIter;
    }
  }
}

for (; secondIter != list1.end(); ++secondIter) {
  retval.push_back(*secondIter);
}
```

Код не проверял, но, думаю, направление вы уловите.

Answer (score 4):

Вот предлагаю по-оптимизировать. Использовать класс [QStringRef](https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qstringref.html) чтобы лишний раз не копировать строки, и сравнивать хэши:

```
#include <QVector>
#include <QHash>

template<typename V>
using Hashes = QVector<QPair<uint, V>>;

template<typename V>
Hashes<V> HashItems(const QVector<V> & items)
{
    Hashes<V> result;
    result.reserve(std::size(items));
    for(const auto & i: items)
    {
        result.emplace_back(QHash::qHash(i), i);
    }
    return result;
}

QVector<QStringRef> diff(const QString & str1, const QString & str2)
{
    auto tokens1 = HashItems(str1.splitRef(" "));
    auto tokens2 = HashItems(str2.splitRef(" "));

    // оптимизация, из короткого удалять дешевле
    const auto & large = std::size(tokens1) >  std::size(tokens2) ? tokens1 : tokens2;
          auto & small = std::size(tokens1) <= std::size(tokens2) ? tokens1 : tokens2;

    QVector<QStringRef> result;
    for(const auto & l : large)
    {
        bool unique = true;
        for(auto s = std::begin(small); s != std::end(small);)
        {
            if(l.first != s->first)
            {
                ++s;
            }
            else
            {
                unique = false;
                s = small.erase(s);
            }
        }

        if(unique)
        {
           result.push_back(l.second);
        }
    }

    for(const auto & s: small)
    {
        result.push_back(s.second);
    }
    return result;
}
```

Comment: Это же O(N^2), нет? Да ещё и с удалением из вектора. Ну в смысле это не тянет на оптимизацию.  Да собственно QSet и будет сравнивать хеши. Преимущество решения Левковича в том, что оно O(NlogN) (две сортировки) + один линейный проход. Преимущество решения на QSet в том, что оно записывается коротко и использует стандартные контейнеры, мест для ошибок меньше.

Comment: На малых N (до нескольких тысяч) будут играть роль технические вещи: алокация памяти, кэширование и прочее. Поэтому тут оптимизация техническая, а не алгоритмическая.

Answer (score 3):

Предлагаю более простой вариант - воспользоваться `QSet`, контейнером, предоставляющим быстрый поиск и действия типа пересечения, сложения и вычитания:

```
QStringList MainWindow::diff(const QString &str1, const QString &str2)
{
    QStringList list1 = str1.split(" ", QString::SkipEmptyParts);
    QStringList list2 = str2.split(" ", QString::SkipEmptyParts);
    QSet<QString> set1 = QSet<QString>::fromList(list1);
    QSet<QString> set2 = QSet<QString>::fromList(list2);
    QSet<QString> d = set2.subtract(set1);
    return QStringList::fromSet(d);
}
```

На вашем примере

```
qDebug()<<diff("/dev/sda  /dev/sda1  /dev/sdc  /dev/sdc1", 
               "/dev/sda  /dev/sda1  /dev/sdb  /dev/sdb1 /dev/sdc  /dev/sdc1");
```

Вывод:

```
("/dev/sdb1", "/dev/sdb")
```

---

UPD

По замечанию @Andrej Levkovitch - этот алгоритм действительно не вполне оптимален, можно его улучшить, например, написав собственный `split` сразу в `QSet` и возвращая не `QStringList` a `QSet`. Но повторюсь, частота использования этого участка кода и объем данных говорит о том, что скорее всего узким местом в программе он не будет и оптимизировать его преждевременно не стоит.

---

UPD 2

Не заметил комментария @vegorov под вопросом, мой код в точности реализует его идею вплоть до ответа по поводу скорости работы.

Comment: Вот только он очень уж непроизводительный: вы дважды копируете данные: сначала в list, а потом в set. Мало этого, так вы потом ещё полученный set копируете в list. Вообще и мой вариант, конечно, не очень хорош, было бы свободное время, я бы сделал это через итератор по словам избегая при этом копирования вообще.

Comment: Да, я знаю, но так как по задаче эти строки достаточно короткие и явно такой парсинг не придется делать часто, это не будет узким местом.